# In R, how do you remove links from a dataframe or a string?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'd like to delete all of the links in the dataframe's "messages" column. How can I get rid of links like these?

I also want to remove any words in the text that begin with http: or https.

```
x<-c("Deneme http://www.example.com/x2ABf merhaba Osman https://www.example.edu OZhann www.example.org/xlsEr45?a karalama")
x<-gsub('?(f|ht)(tp)(s?)(://)(((\\w+\\S+|\\W+\\S+)))(*((/)\\w+))',"",x,ignore.case=T)
x
[1] "Deneme  merhaba Osman https://www.example.edu OZhann www.example.org/xlser45a karalama"
```

Expected output:

```
Deneme merhaba Osman OZhann karalama
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple:

```
gsub("(http|www)\\S+", "", x)
"Deneme  merhaba Osman  OZhann  karalama"
```

It builds on `\\S` (upper-case), a shorthand character class matching any character that is not matched by `\\s` (lower-case), namely tabs, new lines, etc. but also, most important in the present case, white space characters.

Comment: Wonderful. Where have you been until now? Thank you so much. I searched but couldn't find it exactly. What does + at the end of capital letter S mean? Thank you again.

Comment: Also, how can I delete links starting with "ftp" through this code? Thanks.

Comment: The `+` sign is a quantifier, meaning "match once or more times". If "ftp" occurs in the same position in the strings as "www" and "http", then you can just expand the alternation group: `(http|www|ftp)`

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble::tibble(URL = c("https:\\example.com",
                       "http:\\www.example.com",
                       "example.net",
                       "example.com",
                       "no_url_1")) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!stringr::str_detect(URL, "\\.net|http|\\.com"))
```

Comment: Thank you @Florian. However, it would be tiring to write all extensions after "example". No way with gsub?

Answer (score -1):

Surprisingly, all of the suggestions were successful. With your assistance, I created the code below. Thank you a lot.

```
x<-gsub('?(f|ht)(tp)(s?)(://)(((\\w+\\S+|\\W+\\S+)))((*((/)\\w+))|*(\\w+))',"",x,ignore.case=T)    
x<-sub('.www.*\\.\\w+\\S+','', x)
x<-sub('.ttp.*\\.\\w+\\S+','', x)
```

Note: The order of the code is important.